# Having issue updating hidden fields for multiple forms

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an ecommerce site in the basket page, trying to add up the quantity fields once they've been updated, but before the form has been submit, so that I can have the total quantity before the form is submit. When the user updates a quantity field, I have a hidden field (quantityUpdated in my example below) that I want to update with the number that its updated to. What my code is currently doing, is updating one of the quantity form hidden fields with any of the quantities that are entered. So if:

Product A is changed to 5 quantity, and Product B's hidden field updates to 5 but A's does not.

Product B is changed to 5 quantity, and Products B's hidden field is updated again.

I'm sure my issue stems from inexperience with working with the each function.

```
$('.quantity').on('change', function() {
    $('.quantity').each(function(){ 
        var quantity = parseFloat($(".quantity").val());
        $('.quantityUpdated').val(quantity);
    })
    $('.quantityUpdated').each(function() {
         quantityUpdated += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
});
```

Each update quantity form's html is set up like this -

```
<form method="post" action="/basket.html" class="updateProdQty" id="updateQtyForm478296">
    <input type="hidden" class="quantityUpdated" value="">
    <input type="text" name="Quantity" value="10" class="quantity"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="updateBask">Update</button>
</form>
```

Edit -

I've updated the code to the following and my hidden fields are now updating perfectly, but adding the value of each is returning NaN.

```
$('.quantity').on('change', function() {
$('.quantity').each(function(){ 
    var quantity = parseFloat($(this).closest('form').find('.quantity').val());
    $(this).closest('form').find('.quantityUpdated').val(quantity);
})
$('.quantityUpdated').each(function() {
     quantityUpdated += parseFloat(this.value);
});
});
```

Comment: Like need the html to assist. Even better, create a stack snippet by using the `<>` icon on the editor tool bar. You can even choose a jquery version from the left-hand side of the snippet editor.

Comment: You need to be more specific about where you apply the value. Right now you're targeting _all_ of the elements with class `quantityUpdated`. You probably only want the local one. Look into using `$(this)`, as in `$(this).closest('form').find('.quantityUpdated')`.